# The formula for computing the final amount if one is earning compound interest is: Final Amount=P(1 + r/n) **nt (** is to the power of)

Tags: python

```
P = original principal amount (initial investment)
r = the nominal annual interest rate (as a decimal)
n = compounding frequency (the frequency that the interest is paid out per year)
t = number of years
```

how do i calculate What is the Final Amount?

i created variables for all the factors of the equation:

```
p = int(10_000) #initial investment
r = int(3.5/100) #annual interest rate
n = int(.25) #compounding frequency
years = input("enter number of years")
integer_years = int(years)
final_amount_of_compound_interest_earned = p(1+r_decimal//n)**n(integer_years)
print(final_amount_of_compound_interest_earned)
```

i got an error message stating: ZeroDivisionError: float floor division by zero, when trying to calculate the final amount of compound interest

please share where i went wrong

Comment: `int(0.25)` is `0`, and so `n` is 0 and then you try to divide by it, which is what the error message tells you.

Comment: Also (though not directly the cause of the error), `r` is 0, because `int(0.035)` is zero. It doesn't seem appropriate to convert `r` or `n` to integer.

Comment: About the maths in your formula: I hope you're aware that n = 0.25 means interests are yielded every 4 years; if you meant 4 times a year, n should be 4.

Comment: What makes you think that p, r & n should be integer values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using int(0.25), python rounds to turn the value to an integer, in this case 0. You don't have to make any of these integers, though. Just keep it as:

```
p = 10_000 #initial investment
r = 3.5/100 #annual interest rate
n = 0.25 #compounding frequency
```

and the `ZeroDivisionError` should go away.

Comment: *"everything should work."* I think OP also needs to fix the multiplication syntax. For example `n(integer_years)` is a valid multiplication in algebra, but not in Python: it will throw, because `n` is not callable. Same for `p(1+r_decimal//n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and tuned your code because the variable "r_decimal" does not exists. And also the equation seems to be wrong.
I added print messages so you understand where is the error.

Basically, you're dividing the annual interest rate by the compounding frequency. The error is saying that you're dividing a number by zero, and this is caused due to the compounding frequency equals to zero.
When you convert a float number into int and by definition, this function trims the values after the decimal point and returns only the integer/whole number part.

So, the real values that you're using are:

- initial investment: 10000
- annual interest rate: 0
- compounding frequency: 0

```py
p = 10_000  # initial investment
r = 3.5/100  # annual interest rate
n = 0.25  # compounding frequency
print(f"initial investment: {p}")
print(f"annual interest rate: {r}")
print(f"compounding frequency: {n}")
years = input("enter number of years")
integer_years = int(years)
final_amount_of_compound_interest_earned = p*(1+r/n)**(n*integer_years)
print(final_amount_of_compound_interest_earned)
```

I don't know what should be the proper equation to get the compound interest, but I think that you should not convert float values to int.

If I do that, for 4 years, this is the output:

```bash
initial investment: 10000
annual interest rate: 0.035
compounding frequency: 0.25
enter number of years4
11400.000000000002
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# No need to use int()
p = 10_000 # initial investment
r = 3.5 / 100 # annual interest rate
n = 0.25 # compounding frequency

# Here you can use int() right on input()
years = int(input("Enter number of years: "))

# Use / instead of //,  because there is no div in formula
# Also, you used r_decimal which was not provided
result = p * (1 + r / n)**(n * years)

print(result)
# if you want to get more beautiful result, use round()
print(round(result, 2)) # with digits after dot
print(round(result)) # without digits after dot
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... how do i calculate What is the Final Amount? ..."*

Here is, *P ( 1 + <sup>r</sup>∕<sub>n</sub> ) <sup>nt</sup>*

```py
P = 10000.
r = 3.5 / 100
n = .25
t = float(input('number of years:  '))
x = P * (1 + (r / n)) ** (n * t)
print(f'$ {x:,.2f}')
```

Output

```
number of years:  10
$ 13,875.93
```

> *"... i got an error message stating: ZeroDivisionError: float floor division by zero, when trying to calculate the final amount of compound interest ..."*

If I run your code, I get the following.

```
enter number of years10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python/example.py", line 6, in <module>
    final_amount_of_compound_interest_earned = p(1+r_decimal//n)**n(integer_years)
NameError: name 'r_decimal' is not defined
```